# Restricting Popover selection to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom

I'm writing my own popover component that will do some text transformation
https://pastecord.com/vegygawece.js. <--- Popover component code
It should work like this:

- when a user selects some text, I want the popover to appear next to that text (either focus or anchor position)
- I want to bind that ONLY to the component the Popover is rendered
  My current issue is that I can trigger the Popover component anywhere on the page,  I want to constrain it to the component where it's rendered
  Parent component code

```js
import { Flex, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Popover from "../../components/popover";

function ResumeEditor() {
  return (
    <Flex bg="lightgrey" width="100%" height="100vh">
      <Text>
        this is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis
        is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is
        an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an
        editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an
        editorthis is an editorthis is an editorthis is an editor
      </Text>
      <Popover
        onTextSelect={() => {
          return;
        }}
      />
    </Flex>
  );
}

export default ResumeEditor;
```

Comment: What if you add the event listener to the parent component instead of `document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **mouseup** event listener, so when you select the text, trigger the event to display the popover.

Comment: The point is not to use CharkaUI but to create my own solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).